# проверка строки на количество палиндромов

Tags: c++

```
/*222)проверить сколько слов в строке читаются справа налево и слева нараво*/ 
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
char s[]="dod lool poop stos";

int proverka(int i, int j) {
    int b = 1;//пусть слово- палиндром
        while ((i > j)) {
            if (s[i] != s[j]) { b = 0; return b; }
            else { i--; j++; }
        }
    return b;
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int k = 0;//счетчик слов
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (isalpha(s[i])) {
            int j = i;
            while (isalpha(s[i])) { i++; }
            k += proverka(i, j);
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "число палиндромов =" << k;
}
//в консоли отвечает 0
```

Comment: Самое время запустить отладчик и смотреть, что происходит.

Comment: Так и навскидку у вас переданный индекс i указывает не на последнюю букву слова, а не пробел за ней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int proverka(int i, int j)
{
    while ((i > j))
        if (s[i--] != s[j++]) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(s[i]))
        {
            int j = i;
            while (isalpha(s[i])) { i++; }
            k += proverka(i-1, j);
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "число палиндромов =" << k;
}
```

Только вот у вас получается, что `xyz5zyx` - не палиндром, а *два* слова...

Кстати, если использовать C++, то как вариант :) -

```
string word;
for(istringstream is(s); is >> word; )
{
    string rev(word);
    reverse(rev.begin(),rev.end());
    k += word == rev;
}
cout << "число палиндромов = " << k << "\n";
```